# Removing/Replacing dynamically created <STYLE> tags (using jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic

I'm using a common technique to create `<STYLE>`s from within my JavaScript/jQuery - much like this

```
$('<style>.tilewidth { width:' + tilesize + 'px; height: ' + tilesize + 'px;}</style>').appendTo('head');
```

I'm doing this to control how certain objects scale (forcing `DIV`s to be square for example) - and it's working fine.

Problem is I rerun the code if the window is re sized - at which point it inserting a new set of `<STYLE>` tags after the existing ones (if someone drag-stretch/shrinks a window it could insert 100s!!)

This works, I should emphasize, because CSS only reads the last entries - but it seems clumsy and nasty and messy and untidy and horrible (it makes reading code in Firebug near impossible!!)

Question is - can I remove the old  tags before inserting the new ones - or should I just force a complete page reload in re size (and if so, how - and won't it be a performance drain)?

Update: as per Robin's answer, I created a function something like this

```
function addStyle(sname,scode) {
  scode = "." + sname + " {" + scode + "}";
  if ($("#style-" + sname).length)
    $("#style-" + sname).html(scode);
  else
    $("<style/>").attr("id","style-"+sname).html(scode).appendTo("head");
}
```

Which works pretty well - thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `style` tag an `id` and remove it? E.g.

```
$('#sizing').remove();
$('<style id="sizing">…</style>').appendTo('head');
```

Actually, second thoughts, you’d be better off just setting the text rather than creating an element over and over again.

```
var sizing = $('#sizing');
if (sizing.length) {
  sizing.text('my new styles');
} else {
  $('<style id="sizing">…</style>').appendTo('head');
}
```

Comment: Nice idea - I adapted it into a function for an easy life (see editted question)

Answer (score 1):

This is'nt really a common technique at all, you'd be better of just setting the styles directly on the elements :

```
$('.tilewidth').css({
                     width:  tilesize+'px',
                     height: tilesize+'px'
                   });
```

that way the elements styles will be updated on resize instead of adding a bunch of style tags.

Comment: So how about when there are 20+ elements in the document which use the same style then? :)

Comment: Does'nt really matter, if they have same class the styles will be applied. jQuery's `css()` function will work for millions of elements as long as you target them correctly.

Comment: To me this is a misleading approach - it's misusing the idea of classes...

You're not saying "Set Class "tilewidth" to have a width of tilewidthpx - what you're saying is "set all elements with a class of "tilewidth" to have this width.

The class is really just a tag - rather than something which has actual content - it's a backwards way of approach the problem.

But it would work - of course

Comment: @JohnPeat - I get what your saying, but this is the way it's done in billions of website, it's the way all libraries do it, and it would be fairly easy to just append styles to an internal stylesheet instead, but for some reason both plain javascript and libraries like mootools and jQuery all decided to do it this way. Now how you do it is up to you, and I certainly get the appeal of an internal stylesheet over inline styles, but I'll just stick to doing it the regular way for now.

Comment: @JohnPeat - strangely enough this question just came up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958098/jquery-speed-difference-between-css-vs-append-to-head) ...