# jquery: speed difference between .css vs append to head?

Tags: jquery, css

We have some kludgy workarounds for an internal app and I was wondering which jQuery/css technique is considered faster / more efficient ...etc.

**Technique A** using .css

```
$( "#doc" ).css( "margin-top", "90px" );
$( "#checkouthelp" ).css( "margin", "50px 50px 0 0" );

$( "#changelanguage" ).css( "float", "right" )
                      .css( "margin", "0 50px 0 0" );
```

**Technique B** .append to head

```
$("<style>")
    .prop("type", "text/css")
    .html("\
    #doc {\
        margin-top:90px;\
    }\
    #checkouthelp {\
        margin:50px 50px 0 0;\
    }\
    #changelanguage {\
        float:right;\
        margin:0 50px 0 0;\
    }")
  .appendTo("head");
```

This is one of those projects that started out small and relatively innocuous, but has developed into a fairly bloaty workaround. **Is it faster to link to an off-site css file or directly change the css rules as I'm doing here.** Speed is the critical issue and the above sample is but a small slice of the growing kludge. [ Thankfully, the root cause is being assessed ...but in the meantime ].

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

Though I haven't done thorough testing, in the few speed tests I've done use Chrome's developer tools, looks like loading rules from an external stylesheet is slower. Will do more testing, but I think I'm probably stuck using `.css`. Thanks for the responses to this post!

Comment: I know speed is the main concern, but I know I wouldn't want to be responsible for maintaining Technique B. I suspect it's also slower but don't have any solid basis for that.

Comment: What about linking to an external style sheet with jQuery vs. the 2 examples above? Again speed is the main concern. Thanks!

Comment: You could combine some of those `.css` calls using an object as the parameter. `$( "#changelanguage" ).css( { "float": "right", "margin": "0 50px 0 0" } );` I would prefer to use the external css sheet, however i don't know what would be faster. Try testing it.

Comment: For a meaningful answer, you will have to put a timer on the various options. Meanwhile, I would guess that direct manipulation of the DOM (Technique A) is going to knock spots of the other techniques. To my mind, Technique 2 must be slower because two thing happen in cascade - putting a new style sheet in place followed by its parsing etc to affect the DOM. Similarly, fetching a style sheet will be slower for the same reasons as Technique 2, plus HTTP/web delays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `.css` is faster than appending to head with the sample you provided. I have created a test case which demonstrates this here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-css-vs-append-to-head

[image]

As far as offsite CSS, its not comparable, because offsite css speed is dependent on the users internet connection, along with your server speed ect. If you have a wicked server and broadband users, I say offsite is much better, otherwise for speed you can only reliably count on javascript.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I'd have to run tests at 30 locations, each with different network speeds/issues. I don't know that I can count on network speeds. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Offsite css is the way to go. with offsite css the browser only needs to make one request which is usually pretty fast.

on the other hand whenever you modify css elements, the browser must reparse the entire dom tree which is probably more expensive.

The other important question is:

Is speed really as important here as you think it is? Maybe the difference is 45ms between these solutions, which is hardly anything you should care about. You should choose a technique which allows you to write code faster and maintain it better, thats where the real time savings will come in.

Comment: I will test a select sub-group of locations and run some network tests. One of the issues we have is that the network is really crappy at the central location where the offsite style sheet would be served from. But maybe ...

Comment: The other issue is the 'death by a thousand cuts' effect due to other kludgy workarounds. I will definitely test the offsite style sheet speeds and compare. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: dont forget that the browser will cache the offsite style sheet, so you will get it for free most of the time. you can also set expiration   of the file to never and just change the path to it when the file needs to change

Comment: ~ Actually, I had forgotten that --- and I hadn't thought of setting expiration. Can I do this without direct access to the internal app itself? Could I pull in a manifest, so to speak, or simply tell the browser to permanently cache it?

Comment: you cannot do this without access to the app to set the response headers of the files. If you have a spare apache server kicking around you could proxy those files and set the headers you need, then make your code use the proxies files. Or if the files never change, just host them yourself on the said apache server.

Comment: The interface stuff doesn't change so, as you suggest, I'm going to try hosting as much as possible myself. The cgi stuff is remote so I'd have to link to those via external server. Well see what type of speeds we get then. Thank you for your time and advice!

Answer (score 1):

I would add  non-semantic classes via jQ. Such as: 'float-right', 'margin-right'. This is a lot cleaner to maintain imo.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. My css knowledge is pretty rudimentary so I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Just to be clear -- those classes would already exist in your style sheet and you would use jQ to add and remove the classes. I assume you can modify your external CSS.

Comment: I can add an external sheet, but can't alter the primary existing one ...yet.